# run gazebo in virtualbox

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have a project that I'm working on which I will use Gazebo to model
robots. I have installed VirtualBox on my Macbook (Mac os x) and
installed two different ubuntu distributions, and installed Gazebo on
each of them, on both installations, I have faced with problems and
was not able to install in one step although I followed every step in
the instructions for ubuntu.

I would appreciate if you can let me know of the version(and the bit,
32 or 64) of Ubuntu which works best with the Gazebo so I can install
that version and install Gazebo on that. I have tried the last version
of Ubuntu which is 12.04 and 11.10. ( I think both of them were 64 bit
distributions)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25/run-gazebo-in-virtualbox/) by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 7676 on 2012-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The biggest problem is running Gazebo in a virtual machine. I've never had any luck with this kind of setup.

The best solution is to setup a dual boot where your second OS is the latest Ubuntu. Then you'll be able to run Gazebo just fine.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

That's not a recent topic but I just let you know that gazebo works in Ubuntu 12.10 under VirtualBox. However, I was not able to make it run with a decent performance in Ubuntu 12.04.

Some extra notes:

- Enable 3D Acceleration (On your host VirtualBox settings->Display->Video).
- Install VirtualBox Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack.
- Install the gnome-session-fallback package on your guest. Make sure you select this desktop when you log in the next time. The performance will be better compared with Unity.
- Do *not* install the guest additions.

I've tried with Gazebo 1.9.x and it is usable.

Enjoy!

---

Originally posted by [Carlos Agüero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/280/carlos-ag%C3%BCero/) with karma: 626 on 2013-07-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

### Setup

- Dell Inspiron 7520 Laptop
- Windows 7 / 10
- Oracle VirtualBox 5.2.18
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS VM

  - Settings -> Display -> 3D Hardware Acceleration Enabled
- Gazebo7

### Fix

**Change BIOS Settings**
If laptop has hybrid GPUs switch to only discrete GPU (nVidia/AMD), otherwise skip. Note: This may not be required.

1. Enter BIOS, Enable Discrete GPUs which disables hybrid (will consume more power)
2. When booted, system (Windows host) will automatically update drivers, then reboot

**Setup VM**

1. Install packages

   ```
     sudo apt remove libcheese-gtk23
     sudo apt install xserver-xorg-core
   ```
2. Reboot VM

### Troubleshooting VM

If you lose mouse and keyboard after the previous step:

1. Reboot VM, on startup hit the `Esc` or `Shift` keys to enter **grub** startup menu
2. Select ***Advanced Options***
3. Select ***Ubuntu-Kernel-xxxxx (recovery)*** (Should be the first recovery option)
4. Select ***Network*** to get network access
5. Select ***Drop to root shell***
6. Install mouse and keyboard packages

   ```
     apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
   ```
7. Press `Ctrl-D` to leave root shell
8. Select ***Resume***

---

Originally posted by [m1kelyons](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6918/m1kelyons/) with karma: 11 on 2018-10-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1